# Apache Flink Using Windows to induce a delay before writing to Sink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am wondering is possible with Flink windowing to induce a 10 minute delay from when the data enters the pipeline until it is written to a table in Cassandra.

My initial intention was to write each transaction to a table in Cassandra and query the table using a range key at the web layer but due to the volume of data, I am looking at options to delay the write for N seconds. This means that my table will only ever have data that is at least 10 minutes old.

The small diagram below shows 10 minute windows that roll every minute. As time moves on I only want to write data to Cassandra that is older than 10 minutes (the parts in green). I guess is this even possible with Flink?

[image]

I could create 11 minute windows that roll every minute but I would end up throwing 90% of the data away, which seems a waste.

**Final Solution**

I created my own flavour of `FlinkKafkaConsumer09` called `DelayedKafkaConsumer` The main reason for this is to override the creation of the `KafkaFetcher`

```
public class DelayedKafkaConsumer<T> extends FlinkKafkaConsumer09<T> {

    private ConsumerRecordFunction applyDelayAction;

    .............

    @Override
    protected AbstractFetcher<T, ?> createFetcher(SourceContext<T> sourceContext, Map<KafkaTopicPartition, Long> assignedPartitionsWithInitialOffsets,
                                                  SerializedValue<AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<T>> watermarksPeriodic,
                                                  SerializedValue<AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks<T>> watermarksPunctuated,
                                                  StreamingRuntimeContext runtimeContext, OffsetCommitMode offsetCommitMode) throws Exception {
        return new DelayedKafkaFetcher<>(
            sourceContext, assignedPartitionsWithInitialOffsets, watermarksPeriodic, watermarksPunctuated,
            runtimeContext.getProcessingTimeService(), runtimeContext.getExecutionConfig().getAutoWatermarkInterval(),
            runtimeContext.getUserCodeClassLoader(), runtimeContext.getTaskNameWithSubtasks(),
            runtimeContext.getMetricGroup(), this.deserializer, this.properties, this.pollTimeout, useMetrics, applyDelayAction);
    }
```

The `DelayedKafkaFetcher` has a small piece of code in it's `runFetchLoop` that sleeps for n milliseconds before emmitting the record.

```
private void delayMessage(Long msgTransactTime, Long nowMinusDelay) throws InterruptedException {

        if (msgTransactTime > nowMinusDelay) {
            Long sleepTimeout = msgTransactTime - nowMinusDelay;
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug(format("Message with transaction time {0}ms is not older than {1}ms. Sleeping for {2}", msgTransactTime, nowMinusDelay, sleepTimeout));
            }
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTimeout);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to batch the data before writing it to Cassandra or shall each record be written to Cassandra as soon as the 10 minutes have passed?

Comment: Yes I want to batch it before writing to Cassandra but only records that are 10 minutes old should be written.

Comment: How long shall the batch be? A specific number of elements or batches of 1 minute?

Comment: I want batches of 1 minute.

Comment: We decided to ignore this approach and build a delay into our Kafka Consumer.

Comment: @john we have a similar requiremeent, how did you achive it? Is your consumer in flink?

Comment: @simpleusr We overrided the KafkaConsumer and implemented the delay logic before committing the offset.

Comment: @john is it possible to share the code?

Comment: @simpleusr I added some details above. I hope that's enough.

Comment: @john thanks for details. As far as I understand, with this implementation a single consumer record blocks the whole fetch loop right (This seems to be occuring in a for lop)?  Or am I mistaken? And how do you use ConsumerRecordFunction? Could you also give detail about that? Many thanks...

Comment: Your correct, it does block the fetch loop. The ConsumerRecordFunction encapsulates the delay function ive already shared. Its abit of a crude solution but so far it has worked for us quite well in production.

Comment: @john Many thanks for your valuable info. In my flink versıon DelayedFetcher will need to derive from Kafka09Fetcher and its runFetchLoop is full of private variables, so I will apply your delaying ConsumerRecordFunction in emitRecord call and this should not make any difference. By the way why did you chose this instead of windowing? I was planning to use windowing for delay but could not succeed and then finally came accross your solution. Thanks again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255101/apache-flink-job-simple-windowing-problem-java-lang-runtimeexception-segmen

Comment: I couldnt find a way to implement it using windowing, plus the volume of data we would have to store in that window would require alot of memory, this was a better tradeoff.

Comment: @john Thanks again...