# Apache flink - job simple windowing problem - java.lang.RuntimeException: segment has been freed - Mini Cluster problem

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Apache flink -  job simple windowing problem - java.lang.RuntimeException: segment has been freed

Hi,

I am  a flink newbee and in my job, I am trying to use windowing to simply aggregate elements to enable delayed processing:

```
src = src.timeWindowAll(Time.milliseconds(1000)).process(new BaseDelayingProcessAllWindowFunctionImpl());
```

processwindow function simply collects input elements:

```
  public class BaseDelayingProcessAllWindowFunction<IN> extends ProcessAllWindowFunction<IN, IN, TimeWindow> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected Logger          logger;

    public BaseDelayingProcessAllWindowFunction() {
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public void process(ProcessAllWindowFunction<IN, IN, TimeWindow>.Context context, Iterable<IN> elements, Collector<IN> out) throws Exception {
        for (IN in : elements) {
            out.collect(in);
        }

    }


  }
```

The problem is,  I am having below error in my local debug process (starting the job from eclipse) :

```
 [2019-01-18 14:38:18,753] INFO Running job on local embedded Flink mini cluster (org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment:114)


 [2019-01-18 14:38:30,825] INFO Source: dataSource -> Flat Map (1/1) (3677b50300c3c432e862af413796ee5d) switched from RUNNING to FAILED. (org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task:940)
TimerException{org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator}
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SystemProcessingTimeService$TriggerTask.run(SystemProcessingTimeService.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$ChainingOutput.emitWatermark(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.emitWatermark(AbstractStreamOperator.java:691)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$AutomaticWatermarkContext$WatermarkEmittingTask.onProcessingTime(StreamSourceContexts.java:264)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SystemProcessingTimeService$TriggerTask.run(SystemProcessingTimeService.java:285)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: segment has been freed
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.emitWatermark(RecordWriterOutput.java:123)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.emitWatermark(AbstractStreamOperator.java:691)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.processWatermark(AbstractStreamOperator.java:759)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$ChainingOutput.emitWatermark(OperatorChain.java:479)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: segment has been freed
    at org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment.put(HybridMemorySegment.java:228)
    at org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment.put(HybridMemorySegment.java:381)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.BufferBuilder.append(BufferBuilder.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.serialization.SpanningRecordSerializer.addRecord(SpanningRecordSerializer.java:97)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.sendToTarget(RecordWriter.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.broadcastEmit(RecordWriter.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamRecordWriter.broadcastEmit(StreamRecordWriter.java:87)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.emitWatermark(RecordWriterOutput.java:121)
    ... 13 more
```

Google search made me think that this error relates to OOM errros so I tried the following (all failed):

I have tried changing  defaultLocalParallelism from  8 to 1 by hack:

```
private static int defaultLocalParallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

public static LocalStreamEnvironment createLocalEnvironment() {
        return createLocalEnvironment(defaultLocalParallelism);
}
```

also tried increasing memory (-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -Xmn512m)  and also tried reducing window size to 10 ms but none of the above helped..

Please advise

**UPDATE**

After comments, in order to narrow down the problem, I simplified the complex job to a single print statement as below but still having the same error:

```
       DataStream<String> dataStream = getSource(KAFKA_DATA_SOURCE_NAME).getDataStream();

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> out2 = dataStream.timeWindowAll(Time.milliseconds(10)).process(new StringDelayingProcessAllWindowFunction());

        out2.print();
```

statement as below but still having the same error.

There is no implementation in process all window function sub class.

```
public class StringDelayingProcessAllWindowFunction extends BaseDelayingProcessAllWindowFunction<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Is there any special setting for mini cluster or any other setting for windowing?

**UPDATE 2**

I confirmed that, this ugly problem occurs only in mini cluster environment:

```
Running job on local embedded Flink mini cluster (org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment:114)
```

When I submitted the same job on test cluster this simple job did not receive error. So the question is how can I run windowing in mini cluster. Trying with 32 bit jdk did not help either..

Comment: I suspect the cause of the problem is in some of the code that you haven't shared. Can we see what the rest of this job is doing?

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, per your comment I simplified the job it just tries to read from kafka, then window and then print to console but even this is giving the same error...

Comment: Is the problem caused by the windowing? (What happens if you leave out the windowing and just print dataStream?) How many events are there in 10ms, and how large is each event?

Comment: BTW, so far this doesn't feel like a great fit for the window API. What are you really trying to do, and why are you forcing it to run without parallelism? (timeWindowAll cannot run in parallel.)

Comment: If this is an OOM situation, then I suggest either your rewrite this so it can run in parallel (e.g., by using a ProcessFunction with ListState, or by keying the stream and using timeWindow), and/or use the RocksDB state backend so the buffering can spill to disk, or use count windows so you can control the batch sizes.

Comment: @DavidAnderson if I comment out windowing part, stream is succesfully printed to sysout. My purpose is to introduce delay before processing items read from kafka source.  To give mode detaıl job1 puts erroneous ıtems to topic 1. job 2 tries to process them after delay.. A sımılıar question has been asked before and I thought windowing would be  appropriate . Do you have other recommendation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159256/apache-flink-using-windows-to-induce-a-delay-before-writing-to-sink?noredirect=1#comment95240334_44159256

Comment: By the way I do not thınk that thıs ıs due to OOM. No OOM indication in my logs . My guess is that it is sth related to  mini cluster but I as I said I am a newbee and not sure

Comment: @DavidAnderson as you can see in my update problem seems to be occuring in local environbment... Any recommendation for that?

Comment: It turned out that this is a problem due to mini cluster . 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291125/apache-flink-mini-cluster-windowing-operator-execution-problem 
Hope this helps someone else